# I want to validate this transaction ID using regex pattern in php

Tags: php, regex

For `4C64I323QW`:

```
<input name="transid" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Transaction ID" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['transid']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '' ?>"  required id="transid" pattern="[\a-z]\{1}\d{2}\[a-z]{1}\d[3]\[a-z]{2}">
```

The pattern above I try to set the pattern but I failed to validate. And others `transid(CO170307.0920 and CI.170212.1200)`  also I tried to set regex pattern but I don't know how to put dot between the numbers and characters. Please I need help from anyone.

Comment: To match a dot you have to escape it like `\.`

Comment: You shouldn't escape the `a` in `[a-z]`. You also don't need `{1}` -- if you don't have a quantifier, things only match once.

Comment: You will need to capitalize your alphabeticals or add insensitive flag.  and {1} is not needed.

Comment: Also it's case sensitive so [a-z] won't match A. You'd need [A-Z] or [A-Za-z] if you want to match either case. You don't need the backslash before the a, and strictly speaking you don't need {1} either because that's the default.

Comment: Your first regex doesn't allow the string to start with a number (4).

Comment: Did you research before asking your question?  Do you know about https://regex101.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wo7r8n/1))

```
 \d[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]{2}
```

The second:  ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JC19ec/1))

```
[A-Z]{2}\.?\d{6}\.\d{4}
```

Comment: thanks it work perfectly but how about this 4C70I3566W and 4C75I3XE9X I want to validate (5)4C70I, for all transid for this format because it similar with five charatecters and numbers at the begining.

Comment: @ErickMongi Try your hand at learning regex patterns.  Go to https://regex101.com/ and chip away at it.  Yes, I can carry on formulating regex patterns for you, but it is better in the long term for you to learn yourself.  ...plus I need to start dinner for my family.  Good luck.